# Change color of line along labels Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to change the colour and thickness of the lines along the Y and X axis.
I don't know what I am looking for in the documentation but have named them line in the code for now.

What is the line called and what should I name it for it to work?

The lines inside the red mark I want to keep but remove grid.
[image]

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas-1"></canvas>
```

JS

```
  var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
  var lineChartData = {
    labels : ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        labelColor : '#fff',
        fontColor : '#fff' ,
        backgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        borderColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBorderColor : '#fff',
        data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
      }
    ]
  }

  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      fontColor: "white",
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          color: "green",
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          color: "blue",
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: options
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the color and thickness of lines (along x and y axis), set **`color`** and **`lineWidth`** property respectively, for both axis­*'s* grid-lines, like so :

```
scales: {
   xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: 'green',
         lineWidth: 3
      },
      ...
   }],
   yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: '#07C',
         lineWidth: 3
      },
      ...
   }]
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
};
var lineChartData = {
   labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
   datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      labelColor: '#fff',
      fontColor: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
   }]
}

var options = {
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
   legend: {
      fontColor: "white",
   },
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
            display: false,
            color: 'green',
            lineWidth: 3
         },
         ticks: {
            fontColor: "white",
         },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
         stacked: true,
         gridLines: {
            display: false,
            color: '#07C',
            lineWidth: 3
         },
         ticks: {
            fontColor: "white",
            beginAtZero: true,
         }
      }]
   }
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: lineChartData,
   options: options
});
```

```css
canvas { background: #222 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas-1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah, is the OP talking about the grid lines? ... doh ^^

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen Yea :P

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

*For those looking to change the generated graph line (not the grid lines):*

---

The `line` options are for the line type graph, similar as you'll have a `doughnut` type and so on. I believe you figured that out, right?

A quick look in my code showed the option `datasetStrokeWidth` which you can use for the thickness. [more info](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/543)

The color option can be found under `strokeColor` for the style options.

As chart.js combines data- & style options, you're options will look something like this:

```
var lineChartData = {
    line: {
        datasets: [
            {
                strokeColor: '#15bedb'                            
            }
        ]
    }
};

var lineChartStyle = {
    line: {
        datasetStrokeWidth: 1
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: lineChartStyle
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I might have been unclear with what lines I am talking about. I mean the lines along the labels. I marked them in read in a added picture :)

Comment: Ye, no problem. I'll leave my answer just to keep the difference as this might be confusing for others as well. I believe you have a correct answer from @ℊααnd

Comment: The syntax I've used in my answer is from 3.x.
If not applicable, feel free to downvote and I'll remove my answer.